# Temperature of room for open door of refrigerator

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

Will the temperature of the room increase or decrease when the refrigerator door is kept open for a while ?

My book says that , the room temperature increases . But I don’t understand its reasoning.

I want to understand the role of compressor here along with the roles of evaporation and condensation tubes...How do the refrigerants warm up the room ?

Comment: http://www.physlink.com/Education/AskExperts/ae149.cfm did you do any searching online?

Comment: Those are complicated ... I’m on college level ...Ineed some simple understanding

Comment: @A.H.M. That link just explains it in a really simple way.  The "college level" explanation would be based on thermodynamics.  If you read the link pentane gave, it's a really simple description of what happens.

Comment: Assuming this is a garden-variety refrigerator, it cools the compartment by operating an electric motor which "pumps" heat out of the compartment into the surrounding air.  Leaving the door open simply means that the same heat is being pumped around in a circle again and again.  And the electric motor consumes electricity and disperses it as heat ... into the room.

Comment: @pentane...thank you for the link...can you explain using its instruments...?like compressor and coils...

Comment: "_How do the refrigerants warm up the room ?_" How could the net effect do anything else?  All we do is move heat around with refrigeration; but motors/compressors heat up when you use them as well, so the net effect is always heating.

Comment: If you're interested in learning more, they run off vapor-compression refrigeration.  The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor-compression_refrigeration) on it might help a bit.  I know it's also usually covered well in engineering thermodynamics textbooks.

Comment: Go to your fridge. Feel the grill at the back. When the compressor it running, it will be warm.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a mental test.

First, assuming the room temperature decreases when the door is kept open. Therefore, the whole room is cooled down over time. Then you must be curious on where does the heat go. Assuming, the whole room is insulated that there is no heat transfer between the inside and the outside of the room. If you cannot find where the heat leaves the room. Then you at least can conclude that the room temperature doesn't change.

Electricity is consumed by the fridge. You would ask the second equation, where does those the electrical energy go. There is no where it goes. It becomes heat and heats up the room. So the room temperature increases.